# Google maps jumpy, not scrolling smoothly

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Can anyone tell me why my google maps is not scrolling smoothly? The previous versions have no problem with the way it scroll thru the map but lately with the updates it start to behave like this here's a link of our store's Google Map

[Store Locations](http://www.stjosephdrug.com/storelocations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style.css file contains the following entry

```
* {
  transition: transform ease-in-out 250ms;
}
```

This is applied to the map and due to this the scrolling is not smooth. You can test by changing it to 0ms and you'll get the default smooth scrolling in the map.

You can also verify this by creating a new html using the [Simple Map example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) and replacing the code inside the `<script>` tag with your code.

If you are using the transition property somewhere else then you should ensure that it doesn't get applied to the map.

Comment: yup I found it also. I have to dissect my css one by one just to find the culprit. thanks for your detailed answer.